# TypeScript still complaining after checking whether ref is a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

`ref` is a `ForwardedRef<HTMLAudioElement>`. So it can either be a function or an object: `type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null`

I'm checking if `ref` is a function in the if block:

```
const callbackRef = useCallback((node: HTMLAudioElement | null) => {
    if (node && typeof ref === 'function') {
      ref(node);
    } else if (ref) {
      node.volume = volume;
      ref.current = node;
    }
}, [volume]);
```

Then why is TypeScript still complaining in the else if block?

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLAudioElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement | null>'.
  Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLAudioElement | null) => void'.ts(2339)
any
```

Note: I could do `(ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement>).current`, but then why would I even bother checking if `ref` is a function?

Comment: Typescript does not narrow down the type, because you are also checking value of node, so if node is falsey it never reaches the function check. Why are you even checking node if it's type is HTMLAudioElement?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Oh, right. It's type used to be `node: HTMLAudioElement | null`. I don't remember why. I think because it'll be null because the page loads or something. Your comment kind of answers my question, though. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment: Typescript does not narrow down the type, because you are also checking value of node on the same line, so if node is falsey it never reaches the function check. In the first place I imagine that you don't want the function to reach second if statement anyway if node is falsey, since you will not be able to assign volume to it. As such I recommend just aborting early in such a case, which will resolve your issues.

```
const callbackRef = useCallback((node: HTMLAudioElement | null) => {
  if (!node) return;
  if (typeof ref === 'function') {
    ref(node);
  } else if (ref) {
    node.volume = volume;
    ref.current = node;
  }
}, [volume]);
```

Comment: So funny. I did that exact same thing before reading you answer (early abort). But thanks for identifying the root issue!